# Search results label in UISearchbar

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to set search results label like an App Store on iPhone ?

Or like this: [image: http://imageshack.com/a/img809/9499/8htm.jpg]

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the `UISearchDisplayController` class or add a UISearchBar, set the controller you are using to it's delegate and implement the necessary methods.

Apple's Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html